# Ignoring white space when using List.Sort()

Tags: c#, .net

I need to pull data from a text file, sort it, then save over the old data with the newly sorted data.  Here is the format of the text file:

```
Dog

Cow

Sheep
```

If I read the text into an list, then call the sort method, I get this:

```
""
""
""
Cow
Dog
Sheep
```

That's not what I want.  Is there a way for .Sort() to ignore white spaces, or should I approach this problem differently?

*EDIT* I need the empty lines to be there when I save back to the file. The output should be

```
Cow 

Dog

Sheep
```

Comment: Do you need to preserve these empty entries when you read the list or can you ignore them?

Comment: Why don't you ignore them when you construct the list?

Comment: Is each line *always* followed by one empty line, or do you need to remember, "Cow has one empty line after it, Sheep has three, Dog has zero, etc."  If every line just has one line break after it then remove all of the empty lines do the sort, and add them back in when writing the new file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Linq. Following should work:

```
string[] myText = File.RealAllLines("yourfile.txt");
var sortedWithoutEmptyLines = myText
     .Where(t=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t))
     .OrderBy(s=>s)
     .Select(i => string.Concat(i, Environment.NewLine)); //Adding extra linebreak as asked
File.WriteAllLines("yourfile.txt", sortedWithoutEmptyLines.ToArray());
```

Comment: You need to add the line breaks back in when writing the data out again

Comment: File.WriteAllLines will add linebreaks for each item. I see orginal question has been edited with "need to keep empty lines when saving".

Comment: WriteAllLines will add one line break after each item.  The OP needs two line breaks after each item, so you need to add an additional line break after each item, possibly through a simple `Select`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you instead build another `List` with only the non-space strings and sort that. Not only will you save time (if you have empty spaces between each pair of "real" strings you're basically sorting double the data for no reason), but it will be much simpler to write.

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("yourInputFile.txt");
var outputData = lines
        .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) //remove empty lines
        .OrderBy(item => item)
        .Select(line => line + Environment.NewLine); //add them back in
File.WriteAllLines("yourOutputFile.txt", outputData.ToArray());
```

Just take all of the empty lines out, do the sort, and then put them back in.